# How to pop / dismiss specific viewControllers in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Let's say there are two kinds of ViewControllers: `ViewControllerA` and `ViewControllerB`. **If I don't know in which order these two ViewControllers are presented / pushed, is there a way to individually pop / dismiss them without influencing the other?** (Example below)

And if not, how could the example below be implemented while preserving full separation of concerns?

---

If I do:

```swift
navigationController.pushViewController(viewControllerA, animated: true)
```

and

```swift
navigationController.pushViewController(viewControllerB, animated: true)
```

in completely different classes and at different times and don't know in which order they were presented, I will lose one if I do something like:

```swift
navigationController.popToViewController(viewControllerA, animated: true)
// B is lost if it was pushed after A
```

---

An example to illustrate the problem:

Let's say I have two kinds of conditions to access the main screen. For example, if condition A is not met, an overlay of ViewControllerA (e.g. "A message to the user: please fulfil requirement A") is shown and same for B.
If one of them is no longer necessary, because this condition is fulfilled, I want to dismiss / pop it, while the other should be kept.
Due to separation of concerns (the conditions might be of completely different nature, such as some location restriction or time restriction when using the app) the presentation and dismissal should be handled completely separate and independent.

Comment: the behaviour you said with navigation controller pop to specific controller is correct and expected. If your stack has [A, B, C, D], and you want to just remove B so that your new stack order is [A, C, D], you can achieve this by updating the `viewControllers` property in UINavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is not possible.

A navigation controller manages a **stack** of view controllers. After pushing multiple view controllers, you have to pop all the view controllers on top of a given view controller in order to expose it again. If you have a stack [A, B, C, D] (with D on top) you can't pop C out from between B and D.

Note that you could create your own parent view controller class that manages an **array** of child view controllers, and DOES allow you to remove view controllers from arbitrary positions in it's array of children, but you'd be responsible for working out that logic.

### Edit:

What I said is not quite correct. @TejaNandamuri points out that navigation controllers allow you to replace the array of view controllers that they manage (Their "stack").

If you had a stack [Main, A, B] (where "Main" is the root and B is the top-most view controller that's currently visible, and A and B are "overlays", you could add an extension to your navigation controller `removeViewControllerFromStackIfPresent(_ viewControllerToRemove: UIViewController)'. Something like this:

```
extension UINavigationController {
    func removeViewControllerFromStackIfPresent(_ viewControllerToRemove: UIViewController) {
        if let index = viewControllers.firstIndex(where: { vc in
            vc == viewControllerToRemove
        }) {
            var newStack = viewControllers
            newStack.remove(at: index)
            setViewControllers(newStack, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your ViewControllerA and ViewControllerB when they determine that they are no longer needed, they could call `self.navigationController. removeViewControllerFromStackIfPresent(self)` to remove themselves from the stack.

(Note that you will need to tell your navigation stack not to show a back button.)

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by: "working out that logic"? How would I approach this? Could you give some example or point me to a relevant resource?

Comment: Navigation controllers are a type of parent view controller that manages a stack of child view controllers. (Think of a stack of plates.) The only way to remove a child from a navigation controller is to pop of off the top of the stack. You can't remove children from the middle of the stack. If you want to create a variant of a navigation controller that allows you to remove children from the middle of the stack, you will need to decide on the rules for such a view controller and the code to implement it.

Comment: Your description of what you want to do is vague, so the first task is to clearly map out your goals and the desired interface for your new parent view controller. Only you can do that since these are your requirements.

Comment: See the edit to my answer.