# How to show and hide multiple overlays independently in swift

Tags: ios, swift

**Goal:**

We want to present and hide **multiple independent** overlays if some condition is met or no longer met.
We need this in order to block user access to our app while preserving the position (current ViewController stack). (e.g. a popup "please enable your location services")

At any point we want to be able to show a fullscreen view (i.e. `ViewController`) that blocks access, this could be done in different places for different views, having independent criteria for showing the blocking view. When either criteria is no longer met, we want to hide this view. Independently, if the other criteria is still met, the other view should still block the app.

---

**Problem:**

Now this cannot be done using:

```swift
navigationController.present(vc, animated: true)
```

since this will only be able to retain one view (ViewController) i.e. if both criteria are met, `present` will be called twice (discarding one viewcontroller), dismissing once will dismiss the viewcontroller, giving access to the app even though it should still be blocked.

A similar problem arises when using:

```swift
navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

This time one would have only the option to pop the latest viewcontroller, if the other is popped (using `popTo...`) the latest is discarded. Therefore, this also is not a solution if either must be able to show / hide independently.

---

How can this be achieved? Preferably by only having a reference to a `UINavigationController` or by using some extension or singleton pattern to improve separation of concerns.

Comment: I imagine one could use something like in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33064908/adding-removing-a-view-overlay-in-swift) but this would also not work with multiple overlays

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pop / dismiss specific viewControllers in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77524728/how-to-pop-dismiss-specific-viewcontrollers-in-swift)

Comment: @TejaNandamuri unfortunately not. The linked question asks whether *it is possible* (which as the answer states it is not, using the provided options), but my question is **how do I implement such a functionality** (using other methods if any) i.e. are there any alternatives

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the functionality of presenting and hiding multiple independent overlays based on different criteria, while preserving the state of your current `ViewController` stack, you can consider using a custom view or `ViewController` management system. This system should be capable of managing the overlays independently and ensure that the appropriate overlay is visible based on the set criteria.

Here's a conceptual approach using a singleton pattern for managing these overlays:

**Create a `ContainerViewController`** to handle presenting the overlays:

```swift
class ContainerViewController: UIViewController {
    private var activeOverlays: [String: UIViewController] = [:]

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func presentOverlay(key: String, overlayVC: UIViewController) {
        guard activeOverlays[key] == nil else { return }

        view.addSubview(overlayVC.view)
        overlayVC.view.frame = view.bounds
        activeOverlays[key] = overlayVC
    }

    func dismissOverlay(key: String) {
        guard let overlayVC = activeOverlays[key] else { return }

        overlayVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
        activeOverlays.removeValue(forKey: key)
    }
}
```

**Create a singleton `OverlayManager`** to handle keeping a single instance of `ContainerViewController` and

```swift
class OverlayManager {
    static private var shared: OverlayManager?
    
    static func getInstance(_ containerViewController: ContainerViewController? = nil) -> OverlayManager {
        guard let containerViewController
        else {
            return shared ?? .init(.init())
        }
        
        guard let shared
        else {
            shared = .init(containerViewController)
            return shared!
        }
        
        return shared
    }

    // Reference to the container view controller
    private weak var containerViewController: ContainerViewController?

    private init(_ containerViewController: ContainerViewController) {
        self.containerViewController = containerViewController
    }

    func presentOverlay(key: String, overlayVC: UIViewController) {
        guard let containerVC = containerViewController else { return }

        containerVC.presentOverlay(key: key, overlayVC: overlayVC)
    }

    func dismissOverlay(key: String) {
        guard let containerVC = containerViewController else { return }

        containerVC.dismissOverlay(key: key)
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```swift
// Create a new `OverlayManager` instance
let overlayManager = OverlayManager.getInstance(.init())
// OR
let overlayManager = OverlayManager.getInstance()

// Get an existing instance:
let overlayManager = OverlayManager.getInstance()

// When a condition is met, and you need to present an overlay, call the `presentOverlay` method.
overlayManager.presentOverlay(key: "location",
                              overlayVC: locationVC)
// When the condition is no longer met, call `dismissOverlay`.
overlayManager.dismissOverlay(key: "location")
```

Each overlay is identified by a unique key, allowing multiple overlays to be managed independently.

**Use enums to manage keys.**

Comment: Doesn't this also discard one of the presented viewControllers once you call `navigationController?.present(overlayVC, animated: true)` again?

Comment: @ambassador, I have edited my answer.